How dense are quotients of smooth numbers?
As usual, call a positive integer $y$-smooth if it has no prime factors greater than $y$. Write $S(x,y)$ for the set of $y$-smooth integers $\leq x$. Write $R(x,y)$ for the set of quotients $\{a/b: a,b\in S(x,y)\}$.
How dense is $R(x,y)\cap [1/2,2]$ in $[1/2,2]$ (say)? For instance: is it the case that, for every $t\in [1/2,2]$, there an element of $R(x,y)$ within distance $x^{-0.01}$ of $t$?
(The answer is clearly "no" for $y = o(\log x)$ (because then $R(x,y)$ is too small) and is easily seen to be "yes" for $y$ larger than $\exp((\log x)^{2/3})$ or so thanks to what is known about the density of $R(x,y)$ (see work of Harman and most recently Younis (https://arxiv.org/abs/2409.05761).)

Related question: what about neighborhoods of $1$, more specifically?
Weaker question: when does the union of neighborhoods of radius $x^{-0.01}$ around the elements of $R(x,y)\cap [1/2,2]$ have measure bounded away from $0$?
See also:
Small quotients of smooth numbers
How dense are (very but not extremely) smooth numbers? Can they be found in most (not very) short intervals?
Smooth numbers in short intervals
How "dense" are smooth numbers?

For neighborhoods of 1 you get something from counting and the pigeonhole principle, right?

@WillSawin Right. I guess that can be bootstrapped into an answer to a weaker version of the original question (by an expansion base 2 of sorts).

Hm, no, not quite, one would need elements of roughly the right size. Though, come to think of it…

Expansion base 2 seems to give something very weak.
